# Run JUnit (JAVA) tests for a whole dataset from .txt file

Tags: java, testing, junit

JUnit is something new for me and I'm testing my app as follows:

```
@Before
code...

@After
code...

@Test
test for data1

@Test
test for data2...

@Test
test for dataN
```

But I don't want my tests to take couple hundreds of lines when I'm testing the same method just for different parameters. I want to do something like this but I want to get results for each test

```
@Test
public final void testAll(){

    String data = load from file
    String bool = load from file
    boolean expectedResult;
    if(bool.equals("T")
        expectedResult = true;
    else
        expectedResult = false;
    assertEquals(expectedResult, testedMethod(data);
}
```

With some kind of loop inside `testAll()` for all the data.

Comment: By the way you can simplify to: `assertTrue(bool.equals("T"), testedMethod(data));`

Comment: I would recomend you [Burst](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/burst-parameterized-tests.html). It's perfect for your needs and much simpler to use than [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) of JUnit4 IMHO.

Comment: You might also look at [Concordion](http://concordion.org), which makes this kind of thing easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a [Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) test.
For example (from the wiki) this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }  
           });
    }

    private int fInput;

    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput= input;
        fExpected= expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}
```

is how one looks like.

You might also want to look into [TestNG's Data Providers](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-dataprovider-example/) which are a bit more usable.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using JUnit's `@Before`/`@After` annotations, you could use a loop and run each test case inside the loop, running the before and after methods yourself.

E.g

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String data = loadData(i);
    boolean expected = loadResult(i);
    myBefore();
    try {
        assertTrue(expected, testedMethod(data));
    } finally {
        myAfter();
    }
}
```